# How do I pass a Consumer/Runnable in case a Flux is empty?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a `Flux` of elements, and I want to log a message in case it contains no elements. I tried this, but it didn't work as expected. The exception wasn't "caught" by my consumer and was handled by Reactor's default handler

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Slf4j
public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test() {
        Flux.empty()
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException()))
                .onErrorContinue((t, o) -> log.warn("Flux is empty"))
                .subscribe();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

```
ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators -- Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at com.example.dynamicgateway.misc.GenericTest.test(GenericTest.java:14)
```

How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mono.defer()` to "catch" an empty flux, log, and then let it move on

```java
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test() {
        Flux.empty()
                .switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> {
                    log.warn("Flux is empty");
                    return Flux.empty();
                }))
                .subscribe(e -> {});
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Or you can switch to an error `Publisher` and then let the subscriber handle it. If *you* chain the subscriber, it can log the error message

```java
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test() {
        Flux.empty()
                .switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> Flux.error(new IllegalStateException("Flux empty"))))
                .subscribe(e -> {}, t -> log.warn(t.getMessage()));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```